# Plotting several figures each with subplots

Tags: matplotlib

I wish to plot a number of figures each with 3 x 1 subplots but the second set is the same as the first, what am I doing wrong? ( I don't want to plot 3 x n subplots).
How do I create mutiple figures each with subplots as my attempts seem to have the second set of subplots the same as the first.

```
xfield = 'Z_1'
binCount = 20
##################### Z ranges
Zrange = '1 >= Z > 0'
RErange1a = REMassEClassEmeasure[REMassEClassEmeasure[xfield]>0]
RErange1  = RErange1a[RErange1a[xfield]<=1]
###################### Redness

alphaVal = .3

fig1 = plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6), dpi=200)
yfield = 'uminusr'
#fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 3, figsize=(12,6)) # make the figure with the size 10 x 6 inches
fig1.suptitle('Plot 1 - Histogram Red Galaxies '+Zrange+' for Elliptical Galaxies')
ax1 = fig1.add_subplot(1, 3, 1)
#ax1.title.set_text('Plot 1 - Histogram Red Galaxies '+Zrange+' for Elliptical Galaxies')
ax1.set_ylabel('Galaxy Count')
ax1.set_xlabel(yfield)
counts, bins = np.histogram(RErange1[yfield].data,bins=binCount)
ax1.hist(bins[:-1],bins, weights=counts)
#fig.legend(loc="upper right")
#plt.axis([0, 3, 0, 0.8])
#plt.show()

yfield = 'CountInCyl'
ax2 = fig1.add_subplot(1, 3, 2)
#ax2.title.set_text('Plot 2 - Histogram Count in Cyl '+Zrange+' for Elliptical Galaxies')
ax2.set_ylabel('Galaxy Counts')
ax2.set_xlabel(yfield)
counts, bins = np.histogram(RErange1[yfield].data,bins=binCount)
ax2.hist(bins[:-1], bins, weights=counts)
#fig.legend(loc="upper right")
#plt.axis([0, 3, 0, 0.8])

        
yfield = 'DistanceTo5nn'
ax3 = fig1.add_subplot(1, 3, 3)
#ax3.title.set_text('Plot 2 - Histogram Count in Cyl '+Zrange+' for Elliptical Galaxies')
ax3.set_ylabel('Galaxy Count')
ax3.set_xlabel(yfield)
counts, bins = np.histogram(RErange1[yfield].data,bins=binCount)
ax3.hist(bins[:-1], bins, weights=counts)
#fig.legend(loc="upper right")
#plt.axis([0, 3,        
#plt.show()

##################### Z ranges
Zrange = '1.5 >= Z > 1'
RErange2a = REMassEClassEmeasure[REMassEClassEmeasure[xfield]>4]
RErange2  = RErange1a[RErange1a[xfield]<=5]
print(len(RErange2))
###################### Redness

fig2 = plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6), dpi=200)
yfield = 'uminusr'
#fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 3, figsize=(12,6)) # make the figure with the size 10 x 6 inches
fig2.suptitle('Plot 2 - Histogram Red Galaxies '+Zrange+' for Elliptical Galaxies')
ax1 = fig2.add_subplot(1, 3, 1)
#ax1.title.set_text('Plot 1 - Histogram Red Galaxies '+Zrange+' for Elliptical Galaxies')
ax1.set_ylabel('Galaxy Count')
ax1.set_xlabel(yfield)
counts, bins = np.histogram(RErange2[yfield].data,bins=binCount)
ax1.hist(bins[:-1],bins, weights=counts)
#fig.legend(loc="upper right")
#plt.axis([0, 3, 0, 0.8])
#plt.show()

yfield = 'CountInCyl'
ax2 = fig2.add_subplot(1, 3, 2)
#ax2.title.set_text('Plot 2 - Histogram Count in Cyl '+Zrange+' for Elliptical Galaxies')
ax2.set_ylabel('Galaxy Counts')
ax2.set_xlabel(yfield)
counts, bins = np.histogram(RErange2[yfield].data,bins=binCount)
ax2.hist(bins[:-1], bins, weights=counts)
#fig.legend(loc="upper right")
#plt.axis([0, 3, 0, 0.8])

        
yfield = 'DistanceTo5nn'
ax3 = fig2.add_subplot(1, 3, 3)
#ax3.title.set_text('Plot 2 - Histogram Count in Cyl '+Zrange+' for Elliptical Galaxies')
ax3.set_ylabel('Galaxy Count')
ax3.set_xlabel(yfield)
counts, bins = np.histogram(RErange2[yfield].data,bins=binCount)
ax3.hist(bins[:-1], bins, weights=counts)
#fig.legend(loc="upper right")
#plt.axis([0, 3,        
plt.show()
```

I am being asked to add more details but my question is straight forward and I don't know where the problem in the code is, so not sure how to reduce code.

Comment: finding the problem is the point of reducing the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know why your code does not work. It is hard to replicate what is going on in your end since we dont have the data.

The code below, does more or less what you want, it creates two figures with subplots. Maybe you can cet some inspiration there. I find it easier to do plotting like the one in your problem (where all the plots are basically the same) in loops

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
binCount = 20

data = {k: {l: np.random.multivariate_normal([0,0], [[0.1, 0.05], [.05, .3]], 500) 
for l in  ('uminusr', 'CountInCyl', 'DistanceTo5nn')}
    for k in ('1.5 >= Z > 1', '1 >= Z > 0')}



for zrange, d in data.items():
    
    fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 3)
    fig.suptitle(f'Plot 1 - Histogram Red Galaxies {zrange} for Elliptical Galaxies')

    for (yfield, data), ax in zip(d.items(), axes):
    
        counts, bins = np.histogram(data,bins=binCount)
        ax.hist(bins[:-1], bins, weights=counts)
        ax.set_ylabel('Galaxy Count')
        ax.set_xlabel(yfield)
```